# ios: EXC_ARM_DA_ALIGN error in release build

Tags: ios, memory-alignment

I have a function in my application, that store data from buffer. It works fine in debug mode both device and simulator, but when I create *.ipa and run it on device, I have EXC_ARM_DA_ALIGN error libstdc++.6.dylib  std::string::_M_replace_safe(unsigned long, unsigned long, char const*, unsigned long)

```
struct stMemoryBlock
{
    stMemoryBlock(void* InData, int InSize)
    {
        data        = InData;
        size        = InSize;
        offset      = 0;
    };
    void*           data;
    unsigned int    size;
    unsigned int    offset;
};
```

//-----------------------------------------------

```
char* cDataCollector::TestMemoryThink(char* Buffer, int BufferSize, int TestOffset, int TestSize)
{
    char* result = NULL;

if (TestOffset + TestSize <= BufferSize)
{
    result = &Buffer[TestOffset];
}

return result;
}
```

//-----------------------------------------------------

```
bool cDataCollector::StoreBinaryData(void* DataBuffer, int DataSize)
{
    bool result = false;

char* InBuffer = (char *)DataBuffer;

if (!mPreparedData && !mPreparedDataSize && !mMemoryMap.size())
{
    unsigned int CountElements  = 0;
    int offset                  = sizeof(unsigned int);
    if (DataSize >= sizeof(unsigned int))
    {
//          CountElements   = *(unsigned int*)(&InBuffer[0]);

        memcpy(&CountElements, InBuffer, sizeof(CountElements));
    }

    result = true;

    for (unsigned int i = 0; (i < CountElements) && result; ++i)
    {
        std::string ThinkName ;
        stMemoryBlock * MemoryBlock = NULL;

        result = result && TestMemoryThink(InBuffer, DataSize, offset, 0) != NULL;
        if (result)
        {
            size_t name_think_size = strlen(&InBuffer[offset]);
            char* think_name = TestMemoryThink(InBuffer, DataSize, offset, 0);
            result = result && (think_name != NULL);
            if (result)
            {
                ThinkName   = think_name;
                offset      += (name_think_size + 1);
            }
        }
```

this line cause an error:

```
ThinkName = think_name;
```

maybe I need another way to read a string from memory location that isn’t word (32-bit) aligned? please,help!